# I want to keep my code running after entering the command

Tags: python

**i want to keep my code running after the user inputs the command**
give me an explanation too guys if u can for similar codes

```
 print(' Enter help ')
    
    data = input(' enter your cmmand : ')
    while True:
    
        if data.lower() == 'help':
            print('''
        If you want to convert days to seconds enter : dts
        If you want to convert hours to days enter : htd
        If you want to convert seconds to days enter : std
        If you want to convert minutes to days enter : mtd
        If you want to convert seconds to hours enter : hts
    
           ''')
        break
    
        if data.lower() == 'dts':
            dts = input('Please enter the number of days : ')
            dts = data * 24 * 60 * 60
            print(data, ' Days Converted to : ', dts, 'seconds')
            break
    
        if data.lower() == 'htd':
            htd = input('Please enter the amount of Hours : ')
    
            days = htd / 24
            print(htd, 'Hours converted to days : ', days)
            break
```

Comment: Put `data = input(' enter your cmmand : ')` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I GOT IT FIXED YAAY**
so the problem was to define a loop break with the exit command
while the exit command is not typed dont close the program and excute other commands

```
data = ""
```

while data.lower() != 'quit':
data = input('> ')

```
if data.lower() == 'help':
    print('''
If you want to convert days to seconds enter : dts
If you want to convert hours to days enter : htd
If you want to convert seconds to days enter : std
If you want to convert minutes to days enter : mtd
If you want to convert hours to days enter : htd
If you want to convert seconds to hours enter : hts

Type QUIT to quit the program!

   ''')
elif data.lower() == 'dts':
     dts = int(input('Please enter the number of days : '))
     res = int(dts * 24 * 60 * 60)
     print(dts, ' Days Converted to : ', res, 'seconds')
elif data.lower() == 'htd':
     htd = input('Please enter the amount of Hours : ')

     days = htd / 24
     print(htd, 'Hours converted to days : ', days)
elif data.lower() == 'std':
    std = int(input('Please enter the amount of seconds : '))
    std1= std / (24 * 3600)
    print(std , 'Seconds Converted to days : ' , "%.2f" % std1 , 'Days')
elif data.lower() == 'mtd':
    mtd = int(input('Please enter the amount of minutes : '))
    mtd1 = mtd / (24 * 60)
    print(mtd , 'Minutes converted to days : ' , "%.2f" % mtd1 , 'Days')
elif data.lower() == 'htd':
    htd = int(input('Please enter the amount of hours : '))
    htd1 = htd / 24
    print(htd , 'Hours converted to : ', "%.2f" % htd1 , 'Days')
elif data.lower() == 'sth':
    sth = int(input('Please enter the amount of seconds : '))
    sth1 = sth / 3600
    print(sth, 'Seconds converted to : ', "%.2f" % sth1, 'Hours')
elif data.lower() == quit :
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use continue instead break

```
print(' Enter help ')

data = input(' enter your cmmand : ')
while True:
    if data.lower() == 'help':
        print('''
    If you want to convert days to seconds enter : dts
    If you want to convert hours to days enter : htd
    If you want to convert seconds to days enter : std
    If you want to convert minutes to days enter : mtd
    If you want to convert seconds to hours enter : hts

       ''')
    continue

    if data.lower() == 'dts':
        dts = input('Please enter the number of days : ')
        dts = data * 24 * 60 * 60
        print(data, ' Days Converted to : ', dts, 'seconds')
        continue

    if data.lower() == 'htd':
        htd = input('Please enter the amount of Hours : ')

        days = htd / 24
        print(htd, 'Hours converted to days : ', days)
        continue
```

if you will use continue loop will skip iteration and go to next iteration

Comment: it will make the code running in loops if i type in help

Comment: Yes. How do you want it?

Comment: like when u enter help it shows the help and keeps the code running for next command like dts

Comment: This code do it. Learn more about continue operator